# How to use mock of one class inside another to JUNIT test a void method for capturing arguments?

Tags: unit-testing, junit, mocking, mockito

Here I Have a class A which is implementing `method1`.

```
class A{
    public void method1(String name){
        classB b = new classB();
        // Some operations
        b.method2(argument1); 
    }
}
```

I want to capture the argument passed to `method2` for which I wrote the below code.

I got the error as the mock is not invoked when I did verify to capture the argument in the below code. Please let me know how to execute this successfully by invoking the mock to capture the argument passed to `method2`

```
class ATest{
    String name = "name";
    @Before
    public void setup{
        class A = new class A();
        class B = Mockito.mock(classB.class);
    }

    public void testmethod1()
    {
        A.method1(name);

        ArgumentCaptor<String> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);

        Mockito.verify(B, Mockito.times(1)).method2(captor.capture());

        String actual = captor.getValue();
        assertEquals("some data", actual);        
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't. Because instances of `A` create their own instances of `classB` when `method1` is invoked, you have no access to it. This isn't a testable design.

Answer (score 0):

`Class B` needs to be a dependency of `Class A` for you to be able to mock it properly. Or it can be a parameter.

```
Class A{
 public final B b;
 public A(B b){
  this.b = b
 }
 public void method1(String name){
  // Some operations
  b.method2(argument1); 
 }
}
```

then in your test pass in the mock when you instantiate `class A`

```
class ATest{
    private B b;
    private A a;
    @Before
    public void setup{
     b = Mockito.mock(B.class);
     a = new A(b);
    }
    // tests...
}
```